# Compute left and right values of nested set starting from flat adjacency list in PHP?

Tags: php, nested-sets, adjacency-list

I'm trying to convert  an **adjacency list to a nested tree** only using PHP. I just need to compute left and right values: `level`, `parent_id` and `root_id` are available:

```
$adj = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 100,
        'name' => 'ELECTRONICS',
        'level' => 0,
        'parent_id' => null,
        'root_id' => 100,
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 101,
        'name' => 'SPARE PARTS',
        'level' => 1,
        'parent_id' => 100,
        'root_id' => 100,
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 102,
        'name' => 'FANS',
        'level' => 2,
        'parent_id' => 101,
        'root_id' => 100,
    ),
    3 => array(
        'id' => 103,
        'name' => 'KEYS',
        'level' => 2,
        'parent_id' => 101,
        'root_id' => 100,
    ),
    4 => array (
        'id' => 200,
        'name' => 'CONSUMER ELECTRONICS',
        'level' => 0,
        'parent_id' => null,
        'root_id' =>  200,
    ),
    5 => array(
        'id' => 201,
        'name' => 'KITCHEN',
        'level' => 1,
        'parent_id' => 200,
        'root_id' => 200,
    ),
    6 => array(
        'id' => 202,
        'name' => 'FRIDGE',
        'level' => 2,
        'parent_id' => 201,
        'root_id' => 200,
    ),
);
```

I have searched a lot and I've to admit I not good at recursion and maybe i messed up the pass-by reference in this.

My not working trial: only roots gets left and right values (computed fine, it seems):

```
$build = function (&$node, $left) use (&$build, $adj) {
    $right = $left + 1;

    foreach ($adj as &$child) {
        if ($child['parent_id'] === $node['id']) {
            $right = $build($child, $right); 
        }       
    }

    $node['left']  = $left;
    $node['right'] = $right;

    return $right + 1;
};

foreach ($adj as &$n) {
    if ($n['id'] === $n['root_id']) { // roots
        $build($n, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with left and right values? May I have some desired output example?

Comment: In nested set model each node has a left value and a right value. Left is always less than right. For each node, the left value is always smaller than descendant left/right values, while right is greater than descendants left/right values. For leafs, left = right +1 holds. I'll add how output looks like. More here: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/NestedSetModel.svg/800px-NestedSetModel.svg.png

Comment: Ah okay, I think I've gotten your issue. … Let me write an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It should be best to first build the nested structure from a flat array, and only then assign correct nodes (left/right). Also in performance terms...

To have a fast lookup from the flat array, I first transformed your `$adj` list into an array with `$id => $val`. And only at the very end, remove those which have parents from the root leafs, so you just can access them linearly at the beginning, just as needed.

```
$mapped["leafs"] = [];
foreach ($adj as $val) {
    $mapped["leafs"][$val["id"]] = $val;
}
foreach ($mapped["leafs"] as $id => &$n) {
    if ($n["parent_id"] !== null) {
        $mapped["leafs"][$n["parent_id"]]["leafs"][$id] = &$n;
    }
}
$cleanup = function (&$n) use (&$cleanup) {
    if (!isset($n["leafs"])) {
        return;
    }

    ksort($n["leafs"]);

    /* now, if you assume to always have maximum two nodes... if you want more, just use leafs and remove that below... */
    $n["left"] = reset($n["leafs"]);
    if (count($n["leafs"]) > 1) {
        $n["right"] = end($n["leafs"]);
    }
    unset($n["leafs"]);
};
foreach ($mapped["leafs"] as $id => &$n) {
    if ($n["parent_id"] !== null) {
        unset($mapped["leafs"][$id]);
    }
    $cleanup($n);
}
$cleanup($mapped);
```

(p.s.: I assumed parent_id being null also a valid check for root, especially as they anyway must not be null for array lookup.)